# Compatibility with matplotlib, python and pandas on RHEL6

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, rhel

I have a manual install of numpy, matplotlib and pandas, basic tests seem to work fine.
Versions here:

```
Numpy 1.8.0
Matplotlib 1.3.1
Python 2.6.6
Pandas 0.12.0
```

When I run this code on this platform (RHEL 6.4) i get the following stack trace.

```
'plot'.format(numeric_data.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot
```

The same code runs fine on Fedora 19 without having to deal with any dtype issues and on that platform I have matplotlib 1.2.1, numpy 1.7.1 and python 2.7.4

So will this not work on the RHEL6.4 Python version

### Code snippit

```
#!/usr/bin/python
### Get the libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas import *

disk_data = read_csv('collectl.sD.fullday.clean', sep=' ', index_col=1, parse_dates=True)

sda_io = disk_data[['sda-Reads','sda-Writes']]
print sda_io[:50] 
sda_io[:1000].plot(grid='on')
plt.show()
```

### Trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./parse-collectl.py", line 19, in <module>
    sda_io[:1000].plot(grid='on')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py", line 1636, in plot_frame
    plot_obj.generate()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py", line 854, in generate
    self._compute_plot_data()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py", line 949, in _compute_plot_data
    'plot'.format(numeric_data.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot
```

Comment: Can you please provide some sample lines from your csv.

Comment: Hello alko, I need to trim the data, (too many columns to paste here) Back in a few hours

Comment: #Date Time sda-Name sda-Reads sda-RMerge sda-RKBytes sda-Writes sda-WMerge sda-WKBytes sda-Request sda-QueLen sda-Wait sda-SvcTim sda-Util sdb-Name sdb-Reads sdb-RMerge sdb-RKBytes sdb-Writes sdb-WMerge sdb-WKBytes sdb-Request sdb-QueLen sdb-Wait sdb-SvcTim sdb-Util
  20131124 09:21:10 sda 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 sdb 0 0 2 1 0 4 8 1 55 55 4
alko, I trimmed the dataset down and it works now so somehow my large csv dataset has issues, I need to chase it down, Reason I did not is that the same exact dataset works fine on Fedora 19

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to alko, who asked for a smaller dataset, I found an issue with the dataset that the newer Fedora19 stack was ignoring.

For other folks, be aware of silent dataset repair that seems to take place on the newer stack on Fedora19

The stack I have on RHEL6.4 below works fine, so this is solved
Numpy 1.8.0
Matplotlib 1.3.1
Python 2.6.6
Pandas 0.12.0